# Maven dependencies of dependencues

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a common project which uses an external HTTP dependency. The pom is like this :

```
<project ...>
    <groupId>organization</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have an other project which uses the common project :

```
<project ...>
    <groupId>organization</groupId>
    <artifactId>other-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>organization</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-project</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

How to get the HTTP dependency in the Maven dependencies of the other project without add the dependency manually ? Can I define a scope, a parent module ?

Comment: The httpclient dependency is automatically in the `other-project` cause it is a so called *transitive dependency*. This means it is available in your `other-project` but if you like to use it directly within your `other-project` (meaning having an `import org.apache.httpclient` in one of your classes I recommend to add it explicitly by adding a dependency into your `other-project`...(This is a best practice).

Comment: Yes, adding the HTTP dependency is a solution but I was looking for a solution to do without. For example, when I define HTTP dependancy, Maven load to me commons-logging without to need reference it.

Comment: You seemed to misunderstand my comment. As I wrote. If you define the dependency to your `common-project` all of the dependencies the `commons-project` has are also your dependencies in your `other-project`.

Comment: Yes but as you said in your comment, I have to define the HTTP dependency in the other-project for using these classes. I know it's the best pratice (I always did that) but I wanted to know if there was another way.

Comment: Yes of course you can simple omit that cause the http is a transitive dependency which will result having it on the classpath as well...

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want to "automatically" have `other-project` depend on `common-project` without having to add it explicitly? You can do that using a parent pom. You add the dependency to the parent pom, and then every child project will inherit all the dependencies declared in the parent (you still need to declare who the parent pom is though)

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarise:

If `other-project` depends on `common-project` and `common-project` depends on `httpclient`, then `other-project` automatically depends on `httpclient`. You do not need to do or add anything. This is just how Maven handles this.

It is recommended, though, to add `httpclient` to `other-project` as dependency if you use it directly in your code. This is no technical requirement, but should help you to have a clear overview over your dependencies and also avoid situations in which a future version of `common-project` suddenly drops `httpclient` and you did not notice that.

Comment: I'd say it's recommended to put `httpclient` into `<dependencyManagement>` of `other-project`. If `common-project` drops `httpclient` - that would be great if it's automatically excluded because the rest of the project doesn't need it (if it does - _then_ `httpclient` should be declared in `<dependencies>`).

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev As I said: Add it if you use it directly in your code.

Comment: Ooops, didn't notice, sorry.